# Unable to import documents in the right collection in Mongodb Atlas Cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I wish to import a JSON file of 3 documents in the 'posts' collection of 'node-angular'.

[image]

I ran the following command, and imported the documents; however they are being created as a different namespace.

```
mongoimport --host <primary cluster name> --collection posts --type json --file C:/Users/H182720/Desktop/testcontent.json --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl –username <username> --password <password>
```

Any guidance on how to import the JSON docs within the 'posts' collection of 'node-angular' would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mongoimport --host <primary cluster name> --collection posts 
--type json --file C:/Users/H182720/Desktop/testcontent.json --jsonArray 
--authenticationDatabase admin --ssl –username <username> --password <password>  
--db node-angular
```

This will import documents into `posts` collection of `node-angular` db.